# convert the file into base64 in elasticsearch for attachment

Tags: json, bash, base64, elasticsearch

Actually, I want to change the file into base64 and attach with my elastic search JSON data.
My Code is given below:

```
    curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/test"

    curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test/?pretty=1" -d '
    {
        "mapping" : {
            "xmlfile" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "attachment": { "type" : "attachment" }
                }
            }
        }
    }'

    curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/xmlfile?pretty=1" -d '
    {
        "attachment" : '`base64 /path/filename | perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g'`'
    }'

    curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test/xmlfile/_search?pretty=1" -d '
    {
        "query" : {
            "text" : {
                "file" : "any text will come here"
            }
        }
    }'
```

When I execute this queries, specially while posting data I get this Error:

> "error" : "MapperParsingException[Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('P' (code 80)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@4daa8b42; line: 3, column: 17]]; ","status" : 400

Is there any solution for this kind of problem? I am trying to change the data into base64 while attaching the file. 
**Help??**

Even, when I give double-quote and execute:

```
    curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/xmlfile?pretty=1" -d '
    {
        "attachment" : "'`base64 /path/filename | perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g'`'"
    }'
```

I get this Error

> {"error" : "MapperParsingException[Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING\n at [Source: [B@39c931fb; line: 2, column: 195]]; ","status" : 400}

**Am I missing anything, here?**

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a lucene or elasticsearch question but rather something related to curl, bash, perl

Comment: It is elasticsearch question regarding attachment type: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/attachment-type.html

Comment: @suraz Please upvote and select the answer if it resolves the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
"attachment" : '`base64 /path/filename | perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g'`'
```

The quotes around `base64` are *unquoting* it for the shell and then backtick-quoting to execute the command. You need another double-quote for JSON.

```
"attachment" : "'`base64 /path/filename | perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g'`'"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have already tried that query with double-quote and still there are some Exceptions. Have to come up with great answer. Still searching....

Comment: @suraz Please update this page with details about the problem. Are "some exceptions" related to this problem or are they something else? A double quote is all that is needed to embed Base64 in JSON.

Comment: @potatoswatterI have updated my questions now. Please check it out.