# Error putting base64 converted string into Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I create a simple mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/ficherosindex?pretty=true' -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "items": {
       "dynamic": "strict",
       "properties" : {
            "title" : { "type": "string" },
            "body" : { "type": "string" },
            "attachments" : { "type": "attachment" }
}}}}'
```

I make `PUT` the `title` and the `body`, leaving `attachments` empty.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/ficherosindex/items/1' -d '{
  "title": "This is a test title",
  "body" : "This is the body of the java",
  "attachments" : ""
}'
```

And then I make the following script to update the `attachments` fields with the content of the `MY_PDF.pdf` file, converting it to `base64`.

```
#!/bin/sh
coded=`cat MY_PDF.pdf | perl -MMIME::Base64 -ne 'print encode_base64($_)'`
curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/ficherosindex/items/1/_update?pretty=true' -d '{
    "doc" : {
            "attachments" : \"${coded}\"
}}'
```

When I run the script I'm getting the following error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "json_parse_exception",
      "reason" : "Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@6c8caddf; line: 3, column: 30]"
    } ],
    "type" : "json_parse_exception",
    "reason" : "Unexpected character ('\\' (code 92)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@6c8caddf; line: 3, column: 30]"
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Maybe I've to change the following line?

```
{
    "doc" : {
       "attachments" : \"${coded}\"
}}'
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12347395/742269) solution with no luck. I have to mantain the order I'm showing. First create the item without the `attachments` and then use the `_update` to append the content of the .PDF to it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `$(coded)` instead of `${coded}` and remove the backslashes in front of the double quotes: `"attachments" : "$(coded)"`

Comment: @Val It doesnt like to contain the `$`: `Illegal character '$' (code 0x24) in base64 content\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.InputStreamStreamInput@43f0f1cc; line: 1, column: 87]"`

Comment: Can you try this instead: `"attachments" : ""$(coded)""` i.e. two double quotes

Comment: It finally worked with `"'"$coded"'"` . The problem now is that I'm getting the `curl: Argument list too long` error. It seems I've to work with files instead of loading the entire string on the fly.

Comment: Can you try to add `-v` to your curl to see the exact payload that is being sent, please?

Comment: Where exactly do I've to add the `-v` ? If I put `curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/ficherosindex/items/1/_update?pretty=true' -d -v '{ [...] }'` no more info is shown, just the `curl: Argument list too long` error.

Comment: Never mind the `-v`, your latest issue is solved here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174350/curl-argument-list-too-long

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was exactly trying but I cant "adapt" that code to my `curl` call. How does that relate the content of the file (which I suppose is the `CURL_DATA` file) to the `$DATA` variable? Can you give me a hand with the exact curl call I've to do please? (you can put it as an answer if you want to so I can accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
#!/bin/sh
coded=`cat MY_PDF.pdf | perl -MMIME::Base64 -ne 'print encode_base64($_)'`

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/ficherosindex/items/1/_update?pretty=true' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- <<CURL_DATA
{ "doc": { "attachments": "$coded" }}
CURL_DATA
```